# Why a list give me a value, yet the other doesnt?

Tags: java, list

```
public class INode
{
    private int value;
    private INode right, down;
    private int row, col;

    public INode(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() 
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public INode getRight() 
    {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(INode right) 
    {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public INode getDown() 
    {
        return down;
    }

    public void setDown(INode down)
    {
        this.down = down;
    }

    public int getRow() 
    {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) 
    {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCol() 
    {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) 
    {
        this.col = col;
    }


}
```

I can get value of a = 8 but for head, even though I use constructor to set up, still give me value = null... dont know why.

And the driver is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class List
{
public static INode head;
public List()
{
    head = new INode(8);

}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    INode a = new INode(8);
    int data = a.getValue();
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(head.getValue());
}


}
```

Please help me a hand guys. Dont understand why when I use a constructor, I cant assign the value to the node, yet when I create an instance, i can...

Thank guys, love you folks! Great help!

Comment: What gives you null. `data` or `head.getValue()`.

Comment: You have never intialized `List` object, its constructor is not called and so `head` is always null until you initialize the `List` object.

Comment: yes, you have never used the constructor. Firstly make an object of List(List list = new List()) then use the head variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not instantiate the class `List`. Change your code to

```
public INode head; // remove static
public List() {
    head = new INode(8);
}
```

And modify your main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    INode a = new INode(8);
    int data = a.getValue();
    System.out.println(data);

    List l = new List(); // create new List instance
    System.out.println(l.head.getValue()); // get the head from List instance
}
```

Another valid alternative would be to change just one line:

```
public static INode head = new INode(8); // create instance during class initialization
```

I recommend to look at the difference between class (static) and instance variables, e.g. in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) (extract follows):

> - Instance Variables (Non-Static Fields) Technically speaking, objects store their individual states in "non-static fields", that is,
>     fields declared without the static keyword. Non-static fields are also
>     known as instance variables because their values are unique to each
>     instance of a class (to each object, in other words); the currentSpeed
>     of one bicycle is independent from the currentSpeed of another.
> - Class Variables (Static Fields) A class variable is any field declared with the static modifier; this tells the compiler that there
>     is exactly one copy of this variable in existence, regardless of how
>     many times the class has been instantiated. A field defining the
>     number of gears for a particular kind of bicycle could be marked as
>     static since conceptually the same number of gears will apply to all
>     instances. The code static int numGears = 6; would create such a
>     static field. Additionally, the keyword final could be added to
>     indicate that the number of gears will never change.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your static variables either at the point of declaration, or in a static initializer block. And not in a constructor.

Constructor will only be used, when you instantiate your `List` class, that you are not doing anywhere. `static initializer` block is executed, when the class is loaded into memoty. So, your `INode` will get initialized when the class is loaded.

```
public static INode head;
static {
    head = new INode(8);
}
```

or just: -

```
public static INode head = new INode(8);
```

- `static` variables are common to all instances. If a change is made
  for one instance, it will be reflected in all the instances. So be
  sure before using them, that you actually want that. If possible, 
  declare your `INode` as `non-static` variable. And instantiate your
  `List class` before  using it.

  ```
  public INode head = new INode(8);
  ```

And then in your main method, you can access it like this: -

```
List list = new List();
System.out.println(list.head.getValue());
```

Comment: A better solution would be removing the `static` keyword for the `INode head` attribute on the `List` class. This way, OP could add more than 1 list in the example.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I had written that earlier in the last statement. Still I have added some more information. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize List object  in main method

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
   new List();
     INode a = new INode(8);
     int data = a.getValue();
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(head.getValue());
```

}

Comment: You initialize the `List` but don't assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either way .. either you can create an instance of Class List or 
you can initialize head to point to object of INode.
This depends on the business logic that you require

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    INode a = new INode(8);
    int data = a.getValue();
    System.out.println(data);
    List list = new List();
    System.out.println(list.head.getValue());

    head = new INode(6);
    System.out.println(head.getValue());
}
```